# fread and fwrite a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, fwrite, fread

Here is my struct:

```
struct Car{
    char plateNum[10];
    char returnDate[7];
    int milage;
    float income;
    struct Car * next;
};
typedef struct Car Car;
```

I need to use fwrite and fread to store the value and load back in after. Is there an easy way?

Comment: Read up about [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Comment: There's no easy way until you write a function that does it. Then there is.

Comment: Just remember that the value of the link `struct Car * next;` written to file will be obsolete when you reload the data from file. You will use the input data to create a new list, item by item, link by link.

Comment: As @WeatherVane said, it is crucial that you don't try to reuse any pointer values you write to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write a LL to a file

```
// Be sure to have opened the file in binary mode

Car *x = head;

// Walk the list and write each node.
// No need to write the next field - which happens to be the last one.
//                    v-----------------v size of data before the `next` field
while (x && fwrite(x, offsetof(Car, next), 1, out_stream) == 1) {
  x = x->next;
}
```

To read records from a file into a LL and return the head node:

```
#include <stddef.h>

// Be sure to have opened the file in binary mode
Car *ReadCars(FILE *in_stream) {
  Car Top;
  Top.next = NULL; // code only uses the `next` field of Top

  Car *previous = &Top;
  Car x;

  // While another record was successfully read ...
  while (fread(&x, offsetof(Car, next), 1, in_stream) == 1) {
    // Fill the next field
    x.next = NULL;

    // Allocate space and copy
    previous->next = malloc(sizeof *(previous->next));
    assert(previous->next);
    *(previous->next) = x;

    // Advance to the next
    previous = previous->next;
  }
  return Top.next;
}
```

Comment: If I want to get a single Car at a time when reading and store the in temp variables then call addToBack function to create the list instead can I tweak your code to do so?

Comment: @RyanClaxton I am not familiar with `addToBack()` and cannot well answer your comment, yet it is likely this code can be modified to your needs.  But if `addToBack()` is what I think it is, it would be a _bad_ way to do so if `addToBack()` has to repeatedly walk down a LL to find its end.

Comment: I have a dummy node that stores the end of the list.. my compiler doesnt like "assert" - hold on I think i can do this..

Comment: @RyanClaxton Use `#include <assert.h>`

Comment: Note code could allocate space first and then `fread()` directly into that space. This approach seemed more illustrative.

Answer (score 0):

The following was written off the cuff by me and has not been tested, so it might need tweaking. Please also note; for the sake of time, I have not tested the return value of `fwrite` and `fread` or checked for read errors. YOU SHOULD DO THIS.

## Writing the file

```
int length = lengthOfList(bar); // Assuming you've already created bar as a linked list of Cars
Car foo[length];
putLinkedListIntoArray(&bar, foo); 

FILE* fh = NULL;

if((fh = fopen("filename", "wb")) == NULL) {
    // Error and die
}

fwrite(&length, sizeof(int), 1, fh);
fwrite(bar, sizeof(Car), length, fh);
fclose(fh);
```

## Reading the file

```
FILE* fh = NULL;

if((fh = fopen("filename", "rb")) == NULL) {
    // Error and die
}

int length;

fread(&length, sizeof(int), 1, fh);

Car foo[length];
fread(foo, sizeof(Car), length, fh);
fclose(fh);
relinkCarList(foo, length);
```

## Functions

```
int lengthOfList(Car* start) {
   int length;
   for(length = 0; start->next != NULL; length++) {
       start = start->next;
   }
   return length;
}

void putLinkedListIntoArray(Car* start, Car* array) {
   for(int i = 0; start->next != NULL; i++) {
       array[i] = *start;
       start = start->next;
   }
}

void relinkCarList(Car* array, int length) {
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       if(i < length - 1) {
           array[i].next = array[i + 1].next;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `fwrite(bar, ...)` should be `fwrite(foo, ...)` in the first block of code. You're also using variable length arrays (new in C99). It also seems inefficient to convert to an array just to be able to do a single fwrite call.

Comment: I agree with @dwks. I think it would be more practical to do successive `fwrite`s until you hit the end of the linked list. After all, OP wants to do this with linked lists and not an array.